# Sum of columns with item and item type grouping

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table with

```
seller_id, transaction_type, sub_total, total_commission_fee, refund_fee, cancellation_fee
```

```
3 transaction_type
payment, cancel, refund
```

i want to get the sum of sub_total, total_commission_fee, refund_fee, cancellation_fee for each seller_id

```
sample
seller_id   transaction_type    sub_total   total_commission_fee    refund_fee  cancellation_fee
3           order               40          0                       0           0
4           order               10          0                       0           0   
3           cancel              0           0                       0           3   
3           refund              28          0                       2           0
```

i want result like this

```
seller_id   payment_total(sum of all sub_total transaction_type order)  cancel_total(sum of all cancellation_fee transaction_type cancel)   refund_total (sum of all refund_fee transaction_type refund)
```

i can get total without transaction type.

```
Transaction::groupBy('seller_id')
  ->selectRaw('sum(sub_total) as total, seller_id')
```

Is there a way to get result as i want.
Else i have to do a get request and loop through each one.
This may cause problem when the table becomes big

And what is this kind of operations called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)` to sum the values:

```php
Transaction::groupBy('seller_id')
         ->selectRaw('SUM(IF(transaction_type = "order", sub_total, 0)) AS payment_total, 
                      SUM(IF(transaction_type = "cancel", cancellation_fee, 0)) AS cancel_total,
                      SUM(IF(transaction_type = "refund", refund_fee, 0)) AS refund_total,
                      seller_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly with group by seller id(seller_id). please try to use below query

```
Transaction::groupBy('seller_id')
     ->selectRaw('SUM(sub_total) AS payment_total, 
                  SUM(cancellation_fee) AS cancel_total,
                  SUM(refund_fee) AS refund_total,
                  seller_id')
```